# How to perform sleep state S1 using WINAPI (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, sleep

***Following is code to put system in sleep state S3, I am looking for a way to perform sleep state S1***

```
bool PerformS3() {  
    int wait = 100;
    LARGE_INTEGER WaitTime;
    WaitTime.QuadPart = wait;
    WaitTime.QuadPart *= -10000000;

    HANDLE hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    if(0 == SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &WaitTime, 0, NULL, NULL, TRUE))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(0 == SetSuspendState(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can find description at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373229(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: in Windows, there's no S1 or S3, there's only "sleep mode". How it's implemented depends on a number of factors and is hardware- and software-specific. You can only change that, to some degree, by reconfiguring power settings in Control Panel and BIOS setup.

---

As the article you linked to, [System Power States (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373229(v=vs.85).aspx), hints, Windows Power Management does not expose ACPI power states but rather uses its own states. A somewhat more explicit declaration of that is at [Standby Explained (S1, S3) – Omar Shahine – MSDN Blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/omars/2004/05/11/standby-explained-s1-s3/).

How these map to ACPI ones depend on motherboard capabilities, driver capabilities and system/BIOS settings.

In particular, Sleep mode used to map to either S1 or S3 (depending on BIOS settings), and newer versions of Windows can also use "Hybrid sleep" or "Away mode".

According to [Which sleep mode should I use? S1 or S3? - Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/4281-63-which-sleep-mode) and my personal experience, the S1/S3 switch specifically is either an option in BIOS setup or a jumper on the motherboard.

Judging by your question formulations, you'll probably be fine with "Away mode".